# MySQL adding data from a third table

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join

```
SELECT m.member_name, p.agefield
FROM members m
JOIN profilefields p ON m.member_id = p.member_id
WHERE m.member_gid = 1
```

I want to add 'prefix' and 'suffix' values to the query from a third table 'group'. member_id is the key in every table but I'm having trouble understanding how to make the join. How should it be done? Below is non working piece of code just to see if I'm on right track at all. Thank you.

```
SELECT m.member_name, p.agefield, g.prefix, g.suffix
FROM members m
INNER JOIN profilefields p ON m.member_id = p.member_id
INNER JOIN groups g ON g.member_id = p.member_id
WHERE m.member_gid = 1
```

Comment: Is m table member id field name "member_id" ? Is your query giving any error? m & p and m & g one-to-one relationship tables? Perhaps giving an idea about table structure might be useful.

Comment: you say nonworking piece of code, what is the current result set?

Comment: Also: it is not mandatory in this case but I would keep the joins between linked tables, not indirect linked ones. so, I would use join the groups table to the member table as well. And again, if member_id is the id field, then what is member_gid?

Comment: If you have multiple groups entries for each members entry, you'll need some way to determine which group entry each profilefields entry relates to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your third join to be like below joining with `members` table directly.

```
INNER JOIN groups g ON g.member_id = m.member_id
```

Your query should look

```
SELECT m.member_name, p.agefield, g.prefix, g.suffix
FROM members m
INNER JOIN profilefields p ON m.member_id = p.member_id
INNER JOIN groups g ON g.member_id = m.member_id
WHERE m.member_gid = 1
```

Comment: Yes, I agree as a habit and correct usage but since INNER JOIN is used here, p table should already return an id to retrieve a record, so it doesn't matter for the solution I think. Please correct me if I am wrong. I still suspect on the member_gid field name.

Comment: @smozgur, may be or may not. What if there is missing information between member table and profilefields. In which case joining with p will result in missing information or incorrect data. But in general case, yes should be fine. BTW OP says *'group'. member_id is the key in every table*

Comment: if profilefields contains foreign key and INNER JOIN is used then in this case, using profilefields' member_id instead m's member_id is perfectly fine. However, I still agree with you as I also commented in the original question about linking these tables.

Comment: Actually OP says "member_id is the key in every table", group is in the previous sentence I think. That's why I suspect about member_gid. Anyway, hopefully OP responses somehow and we are all enlightened :)

Comment: @Rahul this is what I needed. I don't know why I didn't try linking it to the first table. Anyways, what comes to the query itself, I had misspelled column name why it gave an error first. Thank you guys for your answers!